Interpretation of $Y_x+X_y$ and $Y_y-X_x$
These are related to two-dimensional divergence and curl, except that addition in divergence is changed to subtraction and vice versa in curl, to get two new operators. Do they have an intuition and/or possible use?
In vector fields with zero divergence and zero curl, it seems that it's possible for these two operators to be non-zero. And it seems that the magnitude of these operators evaluated at a specific point is related to the rate of change of "something" along hyperbolic paths.
Sorry for non-expansive question, but that's really all there is to the question.
